# How can I save my tree which has an exposed rotten root?

Tags: tree-care, rot

I have a large 6m pear tree in my garden, which I have inherited from the previous owner.

One side of the tree roots are exposed as the tree has grown at the boundary between the lawn and a lower patio.

I have noticed part of the root is corky and has ants coming out of it. I would like to save the tree. What do I need to do?[image]

Comment: Is the tree otherwise healthy? Any loss of leaves or anything like that?

Comment: Yes it's doing well.